# ElasticSearch Error: [term] query does not support different field names, use [bool] query instead

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch, lucene

I am currently using **ElasticSearch v2.3.2** and am having an issue debugging an error in the query. The query seems to be working fine, but it is still throwing an error:

> [query_parsing_exception] [term] query does not support different
>   field names, use [bool] query instead

My current ElasticSearch query is as follows:

```
var must = [];

must.push({ not: { term: { 'zip': '00000' }}});

var request = {
    index: 'my-index',
    type: 'property',
    body: {
        from : page * perPage,
        size : perPage,
        query: {
            bool: {
                must,
                filter : [
                    {
                        geo_distance : {
                            distance : range + 'mi',
                            'position' : point
                        }    
                    },
                    {
                        "not" : {
                            "term" : {
                                    "listing.rentForSale" : "R",
                                    "listing.statusCode" : "Rented"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]

            }
        },
        sort: [{
            _geo_distance: {
                "position": point,
                "order":         "asc",
                "unit":          "mi",
                "distance_type": "plane"
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

My initial query had the **"not"** clause inside the **must array** as follows:

```
var must = [];

must.push({ not: { term: { 'zip': '00000' }}});
must.push({ not: { term: { "listing.rentForSale" : "R" }}});
must.push({ not: { term: { "listing.statusCode" : "Rented" }}});

var request = {
    index: 'my-index',
    type: 'property',
    body: {
        from : page * perPage,
        size : perPage,
        query: {
            bool: {
                must,
                filter : [
                    {
                        geo_distance : {
                            distance : range + 'mi',
                            'position' : point
                        }    
                    }
                ]

            }
        },
        sort: [{
            _geo_distance: {
                "position": point,
                "order":         "asc",
                "unit":          "mi",
                "distance_type": "plane"
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

This did not yield the correct results. Moving the **"not" clause** into the **filter array** now yields the correct search results, but it still throws this error. Any ideas how i can clear this error?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing it is to use `bool/must_not`:

```
var request = {
    index: 'my-index',
    type: 'property',
    body: {
        from : page * perPage,
        size : perPage,
        query: {
            bool: {
                must_not: [
                    {
                        "term" : {
                                "listing.rentForSale" : "R"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term" : {
                                "listing.statusCode" : "Rented"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term" : {
                                "zip" : "00000"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                filter : [
                    {
                        geo_distance : {
                            distance : range + 'mi',
                            'position' : point
                        }    
                    }
                ]

            }
        },
        sort: [{
            _geo_distance: {
                "position": point,
                "order":         "asc",
                "unit":          "mi",
                "distance_type": "plane"
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message means that you should expand the composed term-filter to a bool-filter with two clauses:

```
"term" : { "listing.rentForSale" : "R" }
```

and

```
"term" : { "listing.statusCode" : "Rented" }
```

and these two surrounded by `not: { bool: { should: { [both clauses] } } }`

It depends on the exact meaning what you want to get, if you use a `must` or `should` (and beware of the negation and scoring).

hope that helps,
fricke

Comment: I initially had both of these term clause in a bool-filter, but that did not yield the correct search results. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: replace the not: { bool: { should: { [both clauses] } } } by {bool: [{ not: { 
 term: { 'listing.rentForSale': "R" } } }, { not: { term: { 'listing.statusCode': "Rented" } } } ] }